# Нужно чтобы если написать боту в лс команду !print он выполнял этот код, сейчас пишет ошибку(

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def print(email, member: discord.Member):
    cur.execute(f'''SELECT Tier FROM datebase_with_cute_ass WHERE Email = '{email}';''')
    aboba = cur.fetchone()
    if aboba == {'Tier': 'Supporter'}:
        role_1 = member.guild.get_role(990005388034342963)
        await member.add_roles(role_1)
    elif aboba == {'Tier': 'Best friend'}:
        role_2 = member.guild.get_role(990005345793490954)
        await member.add_roles(role_2)
    elif aboba == {'Tier': 'Friend'}:
        role_3 = member.guild.get_role(990005392845189170)
        await member.add_roles(role_3)


bot.run(settings['token'])  # Обращаемся к словарю settings с ключом token, для получения токена
```

текст ошибки:discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: Тест ошибки discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: Из текста ошибки можно понять, что тот, кто вызывал команду (пользователь) не указал обязательный аргумент member. т.е. за место `!print test@gmail.com @упоминание_участника` он написал `!print test@gmail.com`